# I am trying to map two Excel sheets with one common column, I am getting error stating as attribute error

Tags: python, excel

```
import pandas as pd

#file1 = "mapp1.xlsx"
#file2 = "mapp2.xlsx"

file1 = "C:\\Users\\Sudharshan\\Desktop\\file_map\\mapp1.xlsx"
file2 = "C:\\Users\\Sudharshan\\Desktop\\file_map\\mapp2.xlsx"

df1 = pd.read_excel(file1)
df2 = pd.read_excel(file2)

marge = pd.marge(df1, df2, on="Name")

print(marge)
```

Please help here, I get this error when I execute:

> Marge is not an attribute in pandas

I am trying with Jupyter notebook pycharm and google collab

> AttributeError
> Traceback (most recent call last)  in
>
> 10 df2 = pd.read_excel(file2)
> 11
> ---> 12 marge = pd.marge(df1, df2, on="Name")
> 13
> 14 print(marge)
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_*init*_.py in **getattr**(name)
> 256             return _SparseArray
> 257
> --> 258         raise AttributeError(f"module 'pandas' has no attribute '{name}'")
> 259
> 260
>
> AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'marge'

Comment: You have "marge" instead of "merge".

Comment: Thank you, this solves issue

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your code.
it should be pd.merge I think, instead of pd.marge

Also for Combining two excels sheets column wise...

Try this:

Lets Suppose your workbook 1 or excel file 1 has four columns named 'Locations','Employees','Revenue'and 'Profit'. And your excel file 2 has all these columns with some extra columns too. Now you want to merge these four columns from both the files in output.xlsx

So, you can do this:

```
import pandas as pd

excel1 = 'workbook1.xlsx'
excel2 = 'workbook2.xlsx'

df1 = pd.read_excel(excel1)
df2 = pd.read_excel(excel2)

values1 = df1['Locations','Employees','Revenue','Profit']
values2 = df2['Locations','Employees','Revenue','Profit']

dataframes = [values1, values2]

join = pd.concat(dataframes)

join.to_excel("output.xlsx")
```

Comment: Thank you Paras, your answer helps a lot

Comment: Please feel free to Upvote! Happy Coding.